# How to simulate a matrix based on both row and column parameters

Tags: r, matrix, simulation, normal-distribution

I'm looking into simulating columns of normally distributed data whilst sticking to certain rowbased parameters. Specifically, let's say I want to simulate 6 rows of data for 4 columns, where the final column is a sum of the previous 3 columns. Let's say I have the fourth column filled out, and I know what I want for means and standard deviations for the other three columns. Is there a way for me to simulate this?

For a visual representation, my question is essentially how can I fill out the blanks in the following table:

| x | y | z | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ? | ? | ? | 17.42 |
| ? | ? | ? | 11.95 |
| ? | ? | ? | 15.85 |
| ? | ? | ? | 15.93 |
| ? | ? | ? | 14.78 |
| ? | ? | ? | 17.19 |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| mean = 5 | mean = 6 | mean = 5 | mean = 15.5 |
| sd = 1.2 | sd = 1.5 | sd = 1.3 | sd = 2 |

Simulating each column is of course simple enough with rnorm or something similar, but the row sums are then random, and it's important that I maintain control over the variance of the total column. The final column values don't actually need to be known if there's a way to simulate the 4 columns simultaneously, as long as the approximate mean and sd parameters are maintained, and that the 4th column is a sum of the first 3.

I've fiddled with different things such as mvrnorm or rnorm_multi, which allows me a degree of control over the correlation of the columns, but only indirect unreliable influence over the variance of the final column, which again, is a crucial factor.

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

A bit more of my process, with a brief example. If I simulate a dataset with three variables, eg. x, y and z, I can make sure these variables stick to certain means and vars. A brief example with rnorm:

```
dat <- tibble(x = rnorm(200, 5, 1.3),
                  y = rnorm(200, 6, 1.5),
                  z = rnorm(200, 5, 1.7))


dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(total = rowSums(dat))


var(dat2$total)
```

If you run this piece of code, you can see that the variance of the total column changes pretty considerably for each set of simulations. What I want is to be able to simulate data where I can specify a variance I want for the total column. My idea for this was to create the total column first and then somehow simulate the other columns (through something like rnorm), but giving it a rowwide parameter too. I might've been completely off track here, if so I'll happily listen to other solutions.

Comment: Say X, Y and Z are i.i.d normal variables. Then X+Y+Z is also normally distributed (you can prove this mathematically). But then Var(X+Y+Z) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + Var(Z) and mean(X+Y+Z) = mean(X) + mean(Y) + mean(Z). Both parameters are determined. How could you maintain control over them?

Comment: Not sure I completely get the question here, but perhaps my table is a little unclear. I'm not interested in the sum of the variance or the sum of the means of the three variables. Var(X+Y+Z) and mean(X+Y+Z) doesn't matter to me beyond the individual components. The total column is the sum total of each individual row, so in the first row x+y+z would add up to 17.42. The means and variances below the stipled line are the parameters of the columns. So, if this was questionnaire data, each row a participant, each column an item, the total column would be sum scores for each participant.

Comment: I'm going to edit in a small example at the bottom of the post, might help illustrate what I need a bit.

Comment: It depends on how closely you want the data to match. The mean of the three columns, does not match the expected mean of the total column (16 vs 15.5) and the sd is too small (expected would be about `sqrt(1.2^2 + 1.5^2 + 1.3^2)`, 2.319. You could probably shuffle the rows in each column to get close to your desired totals, but they will not be exact. Shuffling the rows within a column would not change the mean/sd for that column, but would change the mean/sd for the total column.

Comment: Yup, that's one line of thought I was exploring. But how to simulate that shuffle? A loose match is fine - much like rnorm doesn't necessarily give you data with the exact mean and sd, I don't need that either. Just an approximation